# Unable to create Nextjs app, node_modules/node-sass issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Unable to create `nextjs` app, `node_modules/node-sass issue`

I'm trying to create a `nextjs` app using the command from their docs (`npx create-next-app@latest`) using the following configs:
Typescript, ESLint, Tailwind and App Router

But halfway through the installation, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\overflow\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\nan\nan_callbacks_12_inl.h(15): message : this line
contains a '{' which has not yet been matched [C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\overflow\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxp
roj]
```

Along with a bunch of many other errors regarding syntax (:, ;, <, >) etc.

The app is created but my package.json is empty (zero dependencies, not even the basic react, react-dom, next) etc.

Then when I try to install a library, for example: react-icons, I run into the same issue regarding node-sass:

```
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\overflow\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\overflow\node_modules\.node-sass-Qvgoe7KO\build
npm ERR! errno -4082
npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\overflow\node_modules\node-sass\build' -> 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\overflow\node_modules\.node-sass-Qvgoe7KO\build'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-23T15_16_31_234Z-debug-0.log
```

I thought it was an error with my node version, but it's updated (18.16.0) and also it's cache cleared (npm cache verify).

I have no idea what the issue, if anyone has any ideas that'd be super appreciated as I'm trying to learn more about nexjs

Comment: Try to check version of `node-sass`(9+) as it supported to above of node.js version(18+) link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: tried re-installing node-sass, wouldn't allow that either

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens because the installation is not able to create a directory/table/file during the installation process, this can happen from several reasons, try the following:

- Run cmd as admin and use the installation command
- Check npm version is the latest for the node version you are using
- Install different version of node (you can use nvm to switch node versions)
- Disable any Malware/Antivirus that may block it.

Good luck

Comment: I tried the above, still the same error. The conclusion I've come to is that my OS isn't supporting the latest Nextjs version. I'm using an i5 CPU and the latest Nextjs requires Windows11 which requires an i7. Probably not what's going on, but that's my best guess.

Comment: Hi @Mathew, As I tried today to create next-app using `npx create-next-app@latest` command and eveything works well!! Even there isn't any issue I found! I am using Windows 10. so,  IMO I don't think so it was the issue of any OS version. Maybe you should try to completly remove cache, update your editors, and try to use that command again. It should work!!